# How to do a right nest functions using pure/native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, payment

How to do a right nest functions and call the function (pmt) in some place in the equation using pure/native JavaScript? Because when I test my script. The result is not displaying. Sorry. I'm new in JavaScript. Thank you

I want to compute first the Payment Function (pmt) and call it to my real equation

```
CEIL(PMT(fieldname1-fieldname2 / (1- (1 / (1 + interest/12)*exp(fieldname22))) / interest/ 12));
```

Here my script:

```
 //fieldname22 = radio button with no. of terms
 //fieldname1 = amount
 //fieldname2 = downpayment

 (function() {
     var interest = 0;
     if (5000<=fieldname1 && fieldname1<=12000) {
         if(fieldname22 == 9) interest=0.994;
         else if(fieldname22 == 12) interest=0.9351;
         else interest=0.994;
     }
     if (12001<=fieldname1 && fieldname1<=30000) {
         if(fieldname22 == 9) interest=0.9383;
         else if(fieldname22 == 12) interest=0.917;
         else if(fieldname22 == 15) interest=0.8607;
         else interest=0.9351;
     }
     if (30001<=fieldname1 && fieldname1<=60000) {
         if(fieldname22 == 9) interest=0.9383;
         else if(fieldname22 == 12) interest=0.8988;
         else if(fieldname22 == 15) interest=0.8429;
         else if(fieldname22 == 15) interest=0.7901;
         else interest=0.9383;
     }

     function PMT () {
         return (fieldname22 * (fieldname1-fieldname2 * Math.pow((fieldname22+1),fieldname22))) / ((interest+1) * Math.pow((interest+1),fieldname22));
     }

     return CEIL(PMT(fieldname1-fieldname2 / (1-(1/(1+(interest/12))*EXP(fieldname22))) / interest/12));
 })()
```

Comment: javascript names are case-sensitive. Use PMT(...) to call your function.

Comment: @Martin Ernst Ok. I change it now. How can I call the PMT function in my equation?

Comment: Why do You set PMT = inside PMT function? Just assign equation to some variable like "var result =" and then return that result. After that you can console.log or assign to value that function with PMT()

Comment: A bit too much changed. `inside` function `PMT` you should write `var pmt = ...` and `return pmt;`. A second question: is `CEIL()` another function you have defined somewhere else or do you mean `Math.ceil()` ?

Comment: its defined already in the plugin that im currently using. How can I combine the result of pmt in the equation?

Comment: Exactly like you do it now: `return CEIL( PMT(...) / interest / 12)`. You missed only one point: you use an `IIFE` (immediately invoced function expression) to return result of `CEIL()`, but you don't catch the result. You should begin with: `var result = (function() {...` or forget the IIFE ( just remove first and last codeline) and then `var result = CEIL(PMT(...)...)`.

Comment: Can you gift me the right script with your changes? If I remove the result = CEIL(PMT(...)...) how can I get the result in the equation?

Comment: my lord, am I the only one who finds this incrementlessness unreadable?

Comment: What do you mean @myfunkyside?

Comment: Ah I see :D Can you help me with my script, please? @myfunkyside

Comment: I created indentation to make it more readable, and removed some characters that made your equations invalid (check them again to make sure they are now right). But there are still errors in your code; for instance you're passing arguments to `PMT()`, but that function doesn't accept any arguments. Read the answer below carefully, I haven't read it all, but he also talks about this and I'm sure many more important and helpful things

Comment: BTW, I don't know if `exp()` is a custom function as well, or if you meant to use `Math.exp()`.. But if it is a custom function, you better write it in uppercase `EXP()` like your other custom functions

Comment: EXP is also a custom function. Ok I will in into uppercase

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd suggest is refactoring that whole swath of code.

There are two hidden errors in the current code that just aren't visible, because you're throwing so many numbers at the screen at one time.

The first is, IIFEs run immediately, and they pass results, but you have to catch them, because there's no way to call them again.

```
var result = (function () {
    /* ...do stuff */
    return stuff;
}());
```

If you don't have a var in front of it, then the return value is just thrown out.
Not good.

Second, you're passing a **lot** of math into the `PMT` function as an argument.

That's great, but your `PMT` function doesn't actually accept an argument.

```
return CEIL(PMT(/*.... lots of stuff */));
```

...but

```
function PMT () { /* no argument */
    /* do more stuff */
}
```

Worse, PMT actually contains broken JS, right now.
It will throw an error when you call it, because of this piece:

```
// + nothing, and then no second argument; two reasons to throw errors, back to back
( fieldname1-fieldname2 * Math.pow ( (fieldname22+1), fieldname22 ) + , )
```

The good news is that there are lots of ways this can be improved and simplified.

The first thing I'd recommend is getting rid of the IIFE; don't wrap that code in a function that fires right away, unless it only runs one time, and it has 0 dependencies, and it needs to run *before* anything else can happen (except other things that have 0 dependencies and need to run before other stuff).

Instead, wrap it in a function that you can call as many times as you want.

```
function calculate (amount, downpayment, periods) {
    /* all of your stuff */
    return CEIL(PMT(/*...*/));
}


function showTotal () {
    var total = calculate(fieldname1, fieldname2, fieldname22);
    console.log("CURRENT TOTAL: ", total);
};


document.querySelector("#calculateTotal").onclick = showTotal;
```

Now it should be easier to catch the value and use it.

The interest tables are a bit of a mess; sure there are a couple of levels of logic that go in, but the way they're written now would make them a mess to maintain.

In fact, there's already one rule in there, where you give the same 15-period term two different rates.
Which is hard to see, because it's stacked so high.

```
var interestLevels = [0, 5000, 12001, 30001, 60000],
    interestBrackets = [
        { default : 0     },
        { default : 0.994,  "12" : 0.9351 },
        { default : 0.9351,  "9" : 0.9383, "12" : 0.917, "15" : 0.8607 },
        { default : 0.9383, "12" : 0.8988, "15" : 0.8429 }
    ];

function getInterestBracket (amount) {
    var bracketLevel = interestLevels.filter(function (level) {
         return level < amount;
    }).length - 1;

    return interestBrackets[bracketLevel];
}

function getInterestAmount (bracket, numPeriods) {
    return bracket[numPeriods] || bracket.default;
}

function getInterest (amount, numPeriods) {
    var bracket  = getInterestBracket(amount),
        interest = getInterestAmount(bracket, numPeriods);

    return interest;
}


var interest = getInterest(amount, numPeriods);
```

It's not perfect, but it should be *much* easier to see what you're doing, and easier to maintain.

As for the Payment, you need to figure out where you're doing your math; is it going to be inside of the `PMT` call?  What are you going to pass into it?

My expectation would be that most magic-numbers should disappear, and be replaced with pre-calculated values or functions.

`annualAmortization(amount, interest)`

Then you need a payment function which *actually* takes arguments and does things with them.

I can't rewrite all of it, because I don't have all of the pieces; some are missing, some are magic numbers that I get pieces of, but other pieces elude me, and figuring out how and why you intended to do things is lost on me (like doing math inside of `PMT(...)` which will never be seen, then doing more math inside the function (which does get used), and passed out...

Comment: I'm using that script in a wordpress plugin called calculated field form. One of the author of the plugin said that start my function like this (function() {
     var interest = 0;
     if (5000<=fieldname1 && fieldname1<=12000) {
         if(fieldname22 == 9) interest=0.994;
         else if(fieldname22 == 12) interest=0.9351;
         else interest=0.994;
     }...... the purpose of this is every no. of terms there's an equivalent of interest and there's a price range too.

Comment: How can I compute the PMT? So I can call it to the equation?

Comment: Forget that, for now. **Where is the answer being saved to?** When you do what the author said, then the answer goes ***nowhere***, unless you save it to a variable: `var answer = (function () { }());`  Where are you putting `answer`?

Comment: The answer is automatically display in a calculated field text box (already existing in form)